# How could I get a YouTube video download offline viewing source code for using in my Android apps?

Tags: mobile

I am developing a  video uploading and video viewing andriod apps and my client need a option as like as youtube apps download video and offline viewing option as like as youtube apps. What should I do ? I am not getting any similar open source codes. Would it possible for anyone of you to give me instruction or if possible share those codes with me.

Comment: What options have you tried? Can we have a list?

Comment: Thanks for replying . Did you understand my need dear brother ? If you use youtube apps in andriod phone you'll see there is a download option. when you click on download it start downloading but it will not store in your phone or SD card . It will be just download for your offline use. when you'll try it without any internet connection it will be run. I need this feature . For that i need some sample codes or idea about it.

Comment: I don't think a library or API exists for your purpose. You'll have to build one yourself.